# Where does this blank line come from

Tags: css

There's a blank line between the header element and the main element.

Where does this blank line come from?

I still can't find out why even though I've already inspected the chrome development tool.

I wanna know the reason why this happens, and a solution to solve this.

I'v found my own solution to solve this, and it was to add a padding which is commented out below. But I don't know how this solution solves this problem? Why does that work out?

```
<body>
    <!-- We want to have a navigation bar. -->
    <header class="main-header">
        <div>
            <a href="index.html">
                uHost
            </a>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="packages/index.html">Packages</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="customers/index.html">Customers</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="start-hosting/index.html">Start Hosting</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <section id="product-overview">
            <h1>Get the freedom you deserve.</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="plans">
            <h1 class="section-title">Choose Your Plan</h1>
            <p>Make sure you get the most for your money!</p>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

#product-overview {
    background: #ff1b68;
    width: 100%;
    height: 528px;
    padding: 10px;
    
}

.section-title {
    color: #2ddf5c;
}

#product-overview h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

/* h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
} */

.main-header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #2ddf5c;
    /* padding: 8px; */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<ul>` element has by default a margin so I added `margin-bottom: 0;` to it

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

#product-overview {
  background: #ff1b68;
  width: 100%;
  height: 528px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.section-title {
  color: #2ddf5c;
}

#product-overview h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}


/* h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
} */

.main-header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #2ddf5c;
  /* padding: 8px; */
}

/*Only change*/
ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- We want to have a navigation bar. -->
  <header class="main-header">
    <div>
      <a href="index.html">
                uHost
            </a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="packages/index.html">Packages</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="customers/index.html">Customers</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="start-hosting/index.html">Start Hosting</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <section id="product-overview">
      <h1>Get the freedom you deserve.</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="plans">
      <h1 class="section-title">Choose Your Plan</h1>
      <p>Make sure you get the most for your money!</p>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, but I wanna know why adding a padding to the header element also solves this problem..

Comment: ^ That's the concept of margin collapse.

Comment: @ObsidianAge: I thought only margin affects other margins. Does padding also affect the margin collapse?

Comment: @FredFredonando - Adding the padding separates the margins from each other so, since they are no longer  adjacent, they can't collapse.